# How to add a grand total row with averages in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Hi I am new to powerbi and I am trying to figure out how to add a grand total row showing averages rather than the sum. The below table is what I have in powerbi desktop now minus the grand total row at the bottom. I am looking to have the averages of each column and the sum of the volume as shown below.

The formula for each of the % columns follows the below format

Within2BD = IF('Team1 Prev Day TAT'[BD_TAT]<=2,'Team1 Prev Day TAT'[caseid])

% Within 2BD =DIVIDE(COUNTA('Team1'[Within2BD]), COUNTA('Team1 Prev Day TAT'[caseID]))
[image: Product/Priority % Within 2BD % Within 3BD % Within 5BD % Within 14CD Volume Group1 Standard 80% 80% 80% 80% 5 Group1 Urgent 43% 51% 71% 100% 106 Group2 Standard 4% 27% 62% 96% 26 Group3 Standard 100% 100% 100% 100% 19 Group3 Urgent 18% 35% 81% 100% 336 Total 49% 59% 79% 95% 492]

Is this possible? Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: @DavidBacci - Yes it has been solved - thank  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick and dirty solution is to add measures for this that perform an aggregation over your values but retain the current value for the chosen plotting dimension. Here I have assumed that the column `Product/Priority` is in the table `Table`:

```
% Within 2BD Avg = 
AVERAGEX ( 
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Product/Priority] ) , // Replace with your chosen dimension 
    [% Within 2BD]
)
```

It is unclear whether the data you have supplied is what an actual data table looks like, or whether this is what a table visual looks like, though!